# SOLVED How to retrieve Ether from old multisig wallet contract?

Tags: contract-invocation

I have a 1.5 years old multisig wallet contract. I am able to import it to Ethereum Wallet (version 0.11.1) through Contracts -> Watch Contract menu and that way I can run some functions on it ("Add owner", "Execute", etc.). After reading the contract code, it would appear that "Execute" is the function that is used to transfer Ether out of the contract. I'm quite hesitant to use it, though.

"Execute" takes three parameters, address, value and data. Is it safe to leave data empty? And is the unit of value wei or ETH? In the contract there is daily limit of 100000000000000000000000000(!). I assume this is wei, which would mean it's 100 million ETH. The contract also has multiple security warnings on it, if there's something there I should take into account, i'd be supper happy to know.

Any help is appreciated! Here's the contract info: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5248e5fd5d3b43126e5352807f75d6a7d6d7eafb

**SOLVED**

The solution in this case turned out to be pretty simple. After syncing geth (fastsync) I was able to import wallet contract by using older version of Ethereum Wallet (0.8.9).

See also this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/4032

Comment: Where's the code???

Comment: Well it's [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5248e5fd5d3b43126e5352807f75d6a7d6d7eafb#code).

Comment: It looks like function `execute` merely performs dynamic invoking, i.e., it takes byte-code as input (`bytes _data`) and executes it. This doesn't have anything to do with withdrawing ether from the contract, and as a matter of fact, since none of the functions in this contract is `payable`, I doubt that there is any ether in it to begin with. Is it possible that the ether funds that you refer to are actually located in a contract owned by this `MultiSigWalllet` contract (whose functions can be executed only by the authorized signers of this `MultiSigWalllet` contract)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If there is another contract owned by this contract, I wonder how can I find it. As the Internal Txns show, i have been able to move funds from the contract before. In previous versions of Ethereum Wallet I could simply import the contract and there was user friendly UI on transacting the funds.

Comment: If it helps, i can add monetary bounty for successful retrievement of funds from the contract. Lets start with 0.5 ETH.

Comment: I've tested my code (in the answer below), updated a few things and made sure that it is working. So assuming that you have all the private keys required for the multisig, I can explain to you exactly how to withdraw your funds.

Comment: OK, added to the previous answer; let me know how it works for you...

Comment: That's so cool! I'll need little time to review this. Still on my christmas travels and don't want to execute unkown code with my private keys on it. Plus i don't have fully synced client yet. I'll get back to you as soon as i can!

Comment: NP. Note that I have hard-coded the abi of your contract, as well as the abi and bin of my contract, into the script. So there is no need for you to compile anything. All you need to do (as explained in the answer) is to set those constant values declared at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Also note that the funds will eventually be withdrawn into `WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR`, which should be loaded with a small initial amount. In the answer, I have estimated that 0.2 Ether should do, and I am guessing that probably even less than that should do. But since everything will eventually end up in that wallet, you may as well load it with a little more rather than a little less.

Comment: Oh, also, each signer-wallet should be loaded with a small amount of Ether, in particularly the last one (e.g., suppose that you need 3 out of 5 signers, then the 3rd wallet on the list requires a little more than the first two). My script requires only the private keys of the signers, but you'll need their public addresses as well of course, in order to load some funds into them.

Comment: I added the last comment above as a note in the answer, and added another note on the compiled code (bin and abi) that I have hard-coded into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that I'm completely unsure of, so wait for some responses before you try it...

Implement, compile and deploy the follow contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
    address public myWallet;

    constructor() public {
        myWallet = msg.sender;
    }

    function() public payable {
        myWallet.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Then, from the off-chain, call  function `execute` with the address of this contract and the value that you want to withdraw. Needless to say, all amounts are always in WEI.

Here is a web3.js-v1 example:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let Web3 = require("web3");
let web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);

function deployed(contractName, contractAddr) {
    let abi = fs.readFileSync(contractName + ".abi").toString();
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), contractAddr);
}

async function send(transaction) {
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : block.gasLimit
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}

async function withdraw(amount) {
    let multiOwned = deployed("MultiOwned", "0x5248e5fd5d3b43126e5352807f75d6a7d6d7eafb");
    let myContract = deployed("MyContract", "0xThePublicAddressOfMyContractOnTheMainNet");
    let receipt = await send(multiOwned.methods.execute(myContract._address, amount, []));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
}
```

Like I said, I'm unsure of this answer, so wait for some comments, feedback and suggestions...

---

**UPDATE:**

You can withdraw your funds with a few modifications to the code above.

Step #1 - create a file called `withdraw.js` with the following contents:

```
// These parameters serve as an example:
let ETH_NODE_ADDRESS    = "http://localhost:8545";
let WITHDRAW_WEI_AMOUNT = "1000000000000000000"; // 1 ether
let WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR  = "0x7e5f4552091a69125d5dfcb7b8c2659029395bdf";
let WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY  = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
let REQUIRED_CONFIRMS   = 3;
let SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEYS = [
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005",
];


let MS_CONTRACT_ADDR = "0x5248e5fd5d3b43126e5352807f75d6a7d6d7eafb";
let MS_CONTRACT_ABI  = '[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"removeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_numOwners","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_lastDay","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"resetSpentToday","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_spentToday","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"addOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_required","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_h","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"confirm","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setDailyLimit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"_r","type":"bytes32"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"revoke","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newRequired","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeRequirement","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"hasConfirmed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"changeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_dailyLimit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owners","type":"address[]"},{"name":"_required","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_daylimit","type":"uint256"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Confirmation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Revoke","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newRequirement","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RequirementChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"SingleTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"MultiTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ConfirmationNeeded","type":"event"}]';
let MY_CONTRACT_ABI  = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"myWallet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"}]';
let MY_CONTRACT_BIN  = "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";


let Web3 = require("web3");
let web3 = new Web3(ETH_NODE_ADDRESS);


function deployed(abi, address) {
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), address);
}


async function deploy(abi, bin, args, key) {
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    let handle = await send(contract.deploy({data: bin, arguments: args}), key);
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}


async function send(transaction, key) {
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : block.gasLimit
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, key);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}


async function withdraw() {
    let msContract = deployed(MS_CONTRACT_ABI, MS_CONTRACT_ADDR);
    let myContract = await deploy(MY_CONTRACT_ABI, MY_CONTRACT_BIN, [], WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY);
    let balanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR);
    for (let i = 0; i < REQUIRED_CONFIRMS; i++)
        await send(msContract.methods.execute(myContract._address, WITHDRAW_WEI_AMOUNT, "0x00"), SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEYS[i]);
    let balanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR);
    console.log("balanceBefore =", balanceBefore);
    console.log("balanceAfter  =", balanceAfter );
}


withdraw();
```

Step #2 - set the parameters at the top of this file to whatever you have on your system:

```
let ETH_NODE_ADDRESS    = "http://localhost:8545";
let WITHDRAW_WEI_AMOUNT = "1000000000000000000"; // 1 ether
let WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR  = "0x7e5f4552091a69125d5dfcb7b8c2659029395bdf";
let WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY  = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
let REQUIRED_CONFIRMS   = 3;
let SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEYS = [
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005",
];
```

Note that you'll be using this wallet (`WALLET_PUBLIC_ADDR` and `WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY`) for:

- Deploying the `MyContract` contract that I have described at the top of this answer to mainnet
- Withdrawing the funds from the multi-sig wallet that you have previously deployed to mainnet

So be sure to load some funds into this wallet (I'd say 0.2 Ether should do).

Step #3 - download Node.js and npm from https://nodejs.org/en/, and then install them.

Step #4 - open a command line at the same path where you saved the file `withdraw.js`, and then:

- Run `npm install web3`
- Run `node withdraw.js`

---

**UPDATE #2:**

A few notes on the solution above:

1. Be sure to load some funds into each one of the signer-wallets, in particularly the last one (e.g., suppose that you need 3 out of 5 signers, then the 3rd wallet on the list requires a little more than the first two). My script requires only the private keys of the signer-wallets, but you'll need their public addresses as well of course, in order to load funds into them.
2. Note that I am using the compiled code of both my contract (provided at the top of this answer) and your contract (deployed to mainnet), in order to save you the hustle of doing it yourself (compiling my contract and importing your compiled contract). Nevertheless, you shouldn't trust me with this piece of data, or even suppose someone has hacked this answer and changed it.

So here is how you can do it yourself, in case you decide not to trust me:

```
let MS_CONTRACT_ADDR = "Paste your contract address here, preceded by 0x"
let MS_CONTRACT_ABI  = 'Copy your contract abi from etherscan and paste it here'
let MY_CONTRACT_ABI  = 'Compile my contract and paste its abi here'
let MY_CONTRACT_BIN  = "Compile my contract and paste its bin here, preceded by 0x"
```

Comment: Wow, this turned out to be quite a lot more complex than i hoped it would be. Thank you for the effort! Seems like i have some research to do.

Comment: @JussiR: No problem, so do I get my 0.5 ether? :)

Comment: If this helps me to retrieve the funds then definitely! Probably in any case :) I will look into this later (can't say for sure how soon). But feel free to send me your ethereum address.

Comment: @JussiR: Technically, I thought I could actually try it myself, make sure that it works (on a test-net of course, so free of charge). Since I'm interested to know if it works, I just might do that as soon as I have a free hour or so...

Comment: Sorry for so late reply, been too busy with everything else. If you help me through this i'll up the bounty for 1 ETH :) So, I'v never deployed a contract and I don't event have fully synced Ethereum client. Last time time I tried to sync full blockchain it took so long i gave up. I'm assuming this would be necessary for deploying, testing and running new contracts. Then again I assume there should be existing contracts for this in the blockchain since I have been able to do the transactions before..

Comment: Also, can you help me understand this. Is it really so, that this contract source code has been deployed by me, and every multisig waller deploys their own contract source code into the blockchain? Seems like huge waste of resources, when same contracts could just refer to same source code.

Comment: @JussiR: The amount of work that I am likely to spend on it is not worth 1 ether. I might do it for the sake of challenge, but I'm kinda busy with work at the moment. Also, please note that without your private key, I will not be able to complete this task anyway, so you're gonna have to get access to a synced node one way or another (that is, unless you're willing to share your secret information with a complete stranger).

Comment: Of course, thank you for your effort so far! Let me know if you find it worth to take this challenge some time later. Or alternatively feel free to also name the price that would make it worth it for you. I get the private key thing, though I suppose it would be possible for you to deploy the contract (the one in this answer) and then for me to call it with my private key?

Comment: @JussiR: Yes, but like I said - you will then need to get access to a synced node.

Comment: Ah, true. Read that too hastily. I do wonder, if the easiest solution would be to install older version of Ethereum Wallet (the one i'v used before to interact with the contract) and try to call it from that. If I get a fully synced client that might sill work. As far as i know there hasn't been hard forks in between (yet). Do you know if there's any sense in trying to find presynced node and then compare it with etherescan.io or the like, for some guarantee that it's not corrupt?

Comment: I suppose i'd need a matching version of Geth as well, and not just Ethereum Wallet.

Comment: I'm assuming fast synced chain should be enough, since it will have full current state of the network (just not so secure method to sync)?

Comment: @JussiR: I'm not sure about that. Assuming that this contract of yours has been deployed for a long time, you might need archive data. But like I said, I am not too sure about this. I suppose that you can just give it a try and see what happens. Perhaps archive is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @JussiR: Decoding your contract's constructor arguments on etherscan ([here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x01d260e74954163d15ffa022712c63d8ed23fff35a726cfd6af29f4ff5186631)), and assuming you haven't changed any multisig aspect of the contract after deploying it, I believe that you can set `REQUIRED_CONFIRMS = 2` and `SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEYS = [privateKeyOf("0x05721f157a6c790fb11e01d57abf81c546fc7f78"), privateKeyOf("0x0a9c7aecfe9bd41b15a2ada5720a92687df70af3")]`.

Comment: The day-limit appears to be 100 million ether, so it shouldn't pose any issue.

Comment: The solution turned out to be much simpler (see question update). Sorry I never got to use your code in mainnet. Thank you so much @goodvibration, learned a lot about ethereum and solidity. Send me your ethereum address and I'll send some ETH for your efforts!

Comment: Sent :) Aaand couple more words to allow comment.